# Java Overriding with Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

As I can understand here 'a1' reffed to a class B object which has 'a=200' as an attribute. Therefore I expected program will print 200. But why does this program prints 100 instead of 200?

```
    class A{
        int a=100;
    }

    class B extends A{
        int a=200;

    }

    class Demo{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            A a1=new B(); 
            System.out.println("a : "+a1.a); //Prints 100  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Polymorphism and late binding doesn't apply to fields.

Comment: Fields are not overridden. They are hidden.

Comment: u can't override class instance. a1 is declare type A so for class instance its go for A class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) saying

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through super

So in your case the field `a`  of class `B` hidden  by the super calss `A`

If you want to get the value,

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1=new B(); 
        System.out.println("a : "+a1.a); //Prints 200  
    }
}
class A{
    int a=100;
}

class B extends A{
     public B() {
        super.a=200;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

By declaring a field in class `B` that has the same name as a field in its parent class `A`, you are essentially hiding that field. However, field access on a variable is done based on that variable's declared/static type.

In other words, fields are not polymorphic entities like methods are.

In this case, the variable `a1` is declared as type `A`. The field accessed will therefore be the one in the parent class, `A`.

Comment: is it call hiding or shadowing??

Comment: @nachokk from the JLS on [Shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1): `Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity`.

Comment: mm so in `B` it's shadow `a` ? cause if they are in the same package `A.a` is in part of the scope or im confused?

Comment: @nachokk In this scenario it's [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3). The declared `B.a` is hiding the `A.a`. If you had a static field called `c` and a static method in the same class that declared a local variable `c`, that `c` would shadow the static `c`.